# Почему JButton не меняет размер

Tags: java, jframe

Я начинающий программист на Java(прошу не брать ко вниманию простой и, возможно, неправильный код). Суть моем проблемы в том, что я хочу при нажатии на кнопку `Cube` высветить изображение самого квадрата, но кнопка при компиляции занимает все пространство и я не могу увидеть его. Помогите, пожалуйста, с проблемой.

```
package com.BecomeHuman;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


class MyFrame extends JFrame{
    JLabel label;
    JButton button;

    MyFrame(String name){
        super(name);
        setBounds(200, 300, 300, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        label = new JLabel();
        add(label);
        button = new JButton("Cube");
        button.setSize(50,50);
        button.addActionListener(new btnClick());
        add(button);

        setVisible(true);
    }
    class btnClick implements  ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            label.setIcon(new ImageIcon("cube.png"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В Вашем случае достаточно просто увеличить размер JFrame, т.е. перед setVisible() написать setSize(200, 200). Или попробовать другие размеры, потому что я не знаю какое расширение у cube.png

Comment: Приветствую. Спасибо тебе за ответ. Он мне не помог, но я разобрался в проблеме. Надо было просто распределить все по JPanel. Но все равно спасибо. Хорошего дня_)